# Pre-calculating positions (using ForceAtlas2) of graph in sigma.js using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sigma.js

I'm currently implementing a web application that uses AngularJS, sigma.js & d3.js for visualisations. The dataset is going to be quiet large (excepted 200k nodes on a graph.). I'm in the middle of porting all the sigma code to server side to put as little strain on the browser as possible. I have it so that it will generate the Object of nodes and edges for the sigma graph server side.

My problem is now trying to get the ForceAtlas2 algorithm working on node.js. Is it possible to render the graph serverside? Or atleast, get ForceAtlas2 working server side to record the nodes (x,y) positions so it doesn't have to do ForceAtlas2 client side and just load the static positions?

Comment: For future searchers [vivagraph](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS) has [impressive performance](http://www.yasiv.com/graphs#Bai/rw496) and can apparently render server-side on nodejs (though I haven't used it server-side yet)

Answer (score 0):

sigma.js' current ForceAtlas2 is not yet able to work server side through node.js/io.js because a lot of its code is relying on web workers. It might be possible to shim web workers to make it work server side but, if I recall correctly, this has never been attempted yet.

This said, I really wish to port it to make it work server sider and will probably do it soon when we port sigma.js to a more recent packaging system like commonjs.

So, for the time being, I'd say your options are the following:

- Wait for me to develop a server side compatible version of the algorithm.
- Use the Java version through the Gephi toolkit.
- Try a web worker shim.
- Run the algorithm client side on a dedicated page and return the layout data to the server (ew...)

Could you open an issue on sigma.js' repository so we can work this out together please?

Comment: Webworker API implemented in nodejs, just for reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads

Answer (score 0):

This is another walk-around for this situation.

If the user want to view the dataset of the graph multiple times. When first time the user visit, we can write the x, y coordinates to [window.localStorage]. On user's stop the ForceAtlas2 or some seconds after layout.

When further this user visits, just get the coordinates from localStorage, and we do not need to do the ForceAtlas2 again.

You can get the x, y and nodes coordinates from

```
sigmaInst.graph.nodes()
```

So:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("cachedNodes", JSON.stringify(sigmaInst.graph.nodes()))
```